# How do I set up a convex optimisation problem where the variables to be optimised are input to another function?

Tags: python, cvxpy, circuit, convex-optimization

I am formulating a convex optimisation problem using cvxpy in Python.

The goal is to optimise (minimise) the cost of an electrical network. The cost is a sum of the cost of wires (which depends on the thicknesses of the wires) and the cost of the power source.

The constraints are that the currents delivered to the loads in a network should be above some threshold value and that the thicknesses of the wire must be greater than or equal to zero.

The variables I have used are for the thicknesses of the wires (where the the variable is a matrix where each element corresponds to a different connection within the network- it is a network that connects 4 nodes) and the voltage of the source.

```
T = cvxpy.Variable((4, 4))
source_voltage = cvxpy.Variable()
```

What I am unsure about is the following. I have a function that calculates the currents in all the resistors in my model for this network. This function takes an input the thicknesses of the wires and the voltage of the source and outputs the currents through the loads (these are the currents that form one of my constraints). `load_currents = currents(source_voltage, T)`

I want to optimise the thicknesses and the source voltage but the load currents which are calculated from these variables form one of my constraints. How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: You cannot use black-box constraints. You need to formulate *everything* within cvxpy's framework a-priori solving (or else it cannot *reason* about it and none of the assumptions work out).

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest a way in which to optimise a problem with black box constraints in Python?

Comment: You would need to throw a black-box optimizer at it. (?) Can you describe your problem more precise? There are plenty in sklearn but also other approaches possible. What sascha ment is that you have to go fill cvxpy and define constrainsts there as well, or use different method.

Comment: @user3184950 so I have a function currents() which calculates the current through every resistor in an electrical network. This output depends on the resistances of the transmission lines between each node in the network (which in turn depend on the thicknesses of the transmission line). What I would like to do is optimise the thickness of each wire such the cost is minimised- the cost is a function of the transmission lines and the power source. I.e. if thick wires are used the the cost of the wires is more but less power is required since the loss in the network would be less.

Comment: Can you provide code for function and constraints?

Comment: @user3184950 `constraints = [np.min(load_currents) >= 0.1, np.min(T) >= 0]`, `obj = cp.Minimize(sum(multiply(connections, T)) + source_voltage)`, `prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)`. T is a matrix describing the thicknesses of the transmission lines and connections is a matrix describing the length of each connection (i.e. the length of transmission line).